# How to hide and replace navbar-toggler-icon in Bootstrap 4?

Tags: css, html, bootstrap-4, twitter-bootstrap-4

How do you hide and replace the navbar-toggler-icon in Bootstrap 4? Right now the code below just puts the 'X' below the hamburger menu.

```
<nav class="navbar navbar-toggleable-md">
  <button class="navbar-toggler navbar-toggler-right" type="button" data-toggle="collapse" 
  data-target="#navbarsExampleDefault" aria-controls="navbarsExampleDefault" aria-expanded="false" 
  aria-label="Toggle navigation">
    <span class="navbar-toggler-icon"></span>
  </button>

  <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="navbarsExampleDefault">

     <button class="navbar-toggler navbar-toggler-right" type="button" data-toggle="collapse" 
  data-target="#navbarsExampleDefault" aria-controls="navbarsExampleDefault" aria-expanded="false" 
  aria-label="Toggle navigation">
    <span>X</span>
  </button>
</nav>
```

Comment: Can you explain a little better what you're trying to accomplish?

Comment: I wanted to toggle X and hamburger, so when menu is open I get an X when X is clicked menu closes and hamburger is back using Bootstrap only.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

The code you have now has 2 togglers, but I'm not sure why. You just need to replace the normal `navbar-toggler-icon` with an X..

```
<nav class="navbar navbar-faded navbar-toggleable-md">
    <button class="navbar-toggler navbar-toggler-right py-2" type="button" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#navbarsExampleDefault" aria-controls="navbarsExampleDefault" aria-expanded="false" aria-label="Toggle navigation">
       <span>X</span>
    </button>
    <a href="" class="navbar-brand">Brand</a>
    <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="navbarsExampleDefault">
        <ul class="navbar-nav">
            <li><a href="">Link</a></li>
        </ul>
    </div>
</nav>
```

**EDIT** To toggle between the hamburger toggler icon and a close X, you'd need have both the X and hamburger icon inside the `navbar-toggler`. Add some CSS to handle the `collapsed` state of the navbar.

```
.navbar-toggler>.close {
    display:inline;
}
.navbar-toggler.collapsed>.close, .navbar-toggler:not(.collapsed)>.navbar-toggler-icon {
    display:none;
}
```

http://www.codeply.com/go/fgHv33Q6UM

---

**Update Bootstrap 4.2**

The original question/answer is for Bootstrap 4 alpha. Once Bootstrap 4 was in beta, the `navbar-toggleable-*` classes changed to `navbar-expand-*` which effect the navbar breakpoint. Here is an updated example for Bootstrap 4.2...

https://www.codeply.com/go/9AQ4AsYUph

Comment: I wanted to toggle hamburger icon with X and vice versa that's why I had two.

Comment: codeply is working, but when I tried exactly as shown hamburger and X showing at the same time inline

Comment: It works and answers your question. Follow the codeply example, exactly make sure you include the CSS too.

Comment: It is not working for Bootstrap 4. As "X" is appeared first as after page loaded even though navbar is not collapsed. I toggle once then everything got fixed as hamburger sign appear before toggle and "X".after toggle.

Comment: @MuhammadYasir - Of course the original answer is for v4 alpha. You need to update the Navbar markup for whatever version you're using (the latest is 4.2). But the concept is still the same for the toggler to X icon.

Answer (score 2):

If the close button appears at beginning, try this one

HTML

```
<nav class="navbar navbar-light bg-faded navbar-toggleable-md">
    <button class="navbar-toggler navbar-toggler-right collapsed" type="button" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#navbarsExampleDefault" aria-controls="navbarsExampleDefault" aria-expanded="false" aria-label="Toggle navigation">
       <span class="my-1 mx-2 close">X</span>
       <span class="navbar-toggler-icon"></span>
    </button>
    <a href="" class="navbar-brand">Brand</a>
    <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="navbarsExampleDefault">
        <ul class="navbar-nav">
            <li class="nav-item"><a href="" class="nav-link">Link</a></li>
            <li class="nav-item"><a href="" class="nav-link">Link</a></li>
            <li class="nav-item"><a href="" class="nav-link">Link</a></li>
        </ul>
    </div>
</nav>
```

CSS

```
.navbar{
  button[aria-expanded="true"] > span.close {
    display: inline;
    color: #fff;
    opacity: 1;
  }

  button[aria-expanded="true"] > span.navbar-toggler-icon {
    display: none;
  }

  button[aria-expanded="false"] > span.close {
    display: none;
  }
}
```

Comment: If you're using bootstrap 5. Use this.