# Use X (close) for navbar-toggler-icon in Bootstrap 4 WordPress theme?

Tags: css, wordpress, navbar

I am trying to make the toggler (hamburger) icon become an X.
I have followed another thread [How to hide and replace navbar-toggler-icon in Bootstrap 4?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41874424/how-to-hide-and-replace-navbar-toggler-icon-in-bootstrap-4) and also used the code from [Codeply](https://www.codeply.com/go/fgHv33Q6UM)
I can still not get the icon to changed. I am thinking something is wrong elsewhere.

Here is my nav code:

```html
<div class="container">
            <nav class="navbar navbar-toggleable-md navbar-light">

                <div class="navbar-brand">
                    <?php if ( get_theme_mod( 'wp_bootstrap_starter_logo' ) ): ?>
                        <a href="<?php echo esc_url( home_url( '/' )); ?>">
                            <img src="<?php echo esc_attr(get_theme_mod( 'wp_bootstrap_starter_logo' )); ?>" alt="<?php echo esc_attr( get_bloginfo( 'name' ) ); ?>">
                        </a>
                    <?php else : ?>
                        <a class="site-title" href="<?php echo esc_url( home_url( '/' )); ?>"><?php esc_url(bloginfo('name')); ?></a>
                    <?php endif; ?>
     <button class="navbar-toggler navbar-toggler-center collapsed" type="button" data-toggle="collapse" data-target=".navbar-collapse" aria-controls="bs4navbar" aria-expanded="false" aria-label="Toggle navigation">
                    <span class="my-1 mx-2 close">X</span>
     <span class="navbar-toggler-icon"></span>
     </button>
                </div>
                <?php
                wp_nav_menu(array(
                    'theme_location'    => 'primary',
                    'container'       => 'div',
                    'container_id'    => '',
                    'container_class' => 'collapse navbar-collapse justify-content-end',
                    'menu_id'         => false,
                    'menu_class'      => 'navbar-nav',
                    'depth'           => 3,
                    'fallback_cb'     => 'wp_bootstrap_navwalker::fallback',
                    'walker'          => new wp_bootstrap_navwalker()
                ));
                ?>

            </nav>
        </div>
```

And here is my CSS:

```css
@media screen and (min-width: 200px) and (max-width: 998px){

    .navbar-toggler {
        display: block;
  width: 100%;
  float: none;
  margin-right: 0; 
    }/*
    .navbar-collapse.collapse {
        display: none !important;
    }*/
    .navbar-header {float: none; text-align:center;}
    nav.navbar-collapse.navbar-right.collapse.in {
        display: block !important;
    }
    nav.navbar-collapse.navbar-right.collapse,
    nav.navbar-collapse.navbar-right.collapse ul,
    nav.navbar-collapse.navbar-right.collapse li,
    nav.navbar-collapse.navbar-right.collapsing,
    nav.navbar-collapse.navbar-right.collapsing ul,
    nav.navbar-collapse.navbar-right.collapsing li {
        width: 100%;
    }
 .navbar-toggler>.close {display:inline;}
 .navbar-toggler.collapsed>.close, 
 .navbar-toggler:not(.collapsed)>.navbar-toggler-icon {display:none;}
 .navbar-brand {margin:0 auto;}
 
 #content .container {margin: 170px auto 0;}
}
```

I am not new to html, css, or php, but I am relatively new to BootStrap. 
You will notice navbar-collapse is commented out and that is because it would immediately close the nav. That is an issue by itself. This is a child WordPress theme of wp-bootstrap-starter theme using BootStrap and UnderScores. Any help would be appreciated!

Answer (score 1):

it is the CSS, it should be:

```
.navbar-toggler>.close {
    display: inline;
}
.navbar-toggler.collapsed>.close, 
.navbar-toggler:not(.collapsed)>.navbar-toggler-icon {
    display: none;
}
```